# Is train/validation for parameters only, or for completely different models too?

Tags: cross-validation, model-selection

Having a train and test set split, we can choose the model parameters with the lowest cv-error on the train set. Let's suppose I found with this method the best K in a KNN classifier, and the best features in a logistic regression for a binary classifier. I will also calculate the test error for both models. If I want to pick the best classifier between the two for future data, should I pick the one with the lowest test error, or the one with the lowest cv-error in the train set?

Comment: in principle you should pick the model with the lowest test error, because thats how you expect the model to perform in unseen (out of sample) data.   Though you might have other constraints/requirements on the model that also play a role in this decision like inference latency, training time, etc

Comment: ok but what i don't get is: why is it ok to do it for models, but not for parameters? as far as i understood, choosing a parameter with the lowest test error can lead to overfitting to the test set, and a loss of generalization. wouldn't it be the same issue if i choose the best model this way? doesn't it give you the model that is simply the best tailored for the test set, and not the best overall?

Comment: The idea is that you want to have the model that once trained, is expected to perform as good as possible on new (out of sample) data.  Choosing a test set that is independent of the training data, allows you to estimate this.      When you ask "doesn't it give you the model that is simply the best tailored for the test set, and not the best overall"  Well yes you are choosing the model that performs best on the test set, the assumption is that test set represents well the underlying data distribution you are dealing with, and therefore you are indeed choosing  the best model.

Comment: @Rebb: "ok but what i don't get is: why is it ok to do it for models, but not for parameters?" you are right, it isn't. That is, if you need an estimate for generalization error of the one final model, you cannot use the test set for any kind of modeling decision.

Answer (score 1):

Treat the general modeling approach as a hyperparameter: this part of your overall training and should be decided within the training set (so e.g. using a cross validation within the training data).

If you "flatten" the hyperparameter grid you evaluate, that can be done together with the optimization of the other hyperparameters. As an example with two modeling approaches that both need hyperparameters tuned:

```
hyperparameter set | model |  k |   C | γ 
-------------------+-------+----+-----+---
1                  | SVM   | NA |   1 |  1
2                  | SVM   | NA |  10 |  1
:                  |  :    |  : |   : |  :
26                 | SVM   | NA | 1e4 | 10
27                 | kNN   |  1 |  NA | NA
:                  |  :    |  : |   : |  :
50                 | kNN   |  5 |  NA | NA
```